# Find the relative error $\dfrac{\| \Delta x \|_1}{\| x \|_1}$ of the linear system $A\hat{x}=b+\Delta b$, where $\hat{x}=x+\Delta x$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

> Find the relative error $\dfrac{\| \Delta x \|_1}{\| x \|_1}$ of the
> linear system $A\hat{x}=b+\Delta b$, where $\hat{x}=x+\Delta x$ and
> $x$ is the exact solution of the system $Ax=b$

The $x^*$ solution of $Ax=b$ is given by the maximum argument of $\dfrac{\| Ax \|_1}{\| x\|_1}$ and $\Delta b$ itself is the maximum argument of $\dfrac{\| A^{-1}x\|_1}{\| x\|_1}$. The matrices $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are given by:

$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
= (a_{ij})$

$
A^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 2 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=(c_{ij})$

I know that the following relation is valid: $\dfrac{\| \Delta x\|_1}{\| x \|_1}=\mathcal{K}_1(A)\dfrac{\| \Delta b\|_1}{\| b\|_1}$. $\| A\|_1$ and $\| A^{-1}\|_1$ can be easily calculated. I don't know how to compute $\| b \|_1$ and $\| \Delta b \|_1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By guessing, taking $e_{1}^{(4)}$, the canonical vector of $\mathbb{R}^4$, is easy to see that it is the argument that maximizes the 1-norm, the remaining steps are straightforward.